# How to fetch data through polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism

I have table called audits with the following columns.

```
auditable_id, auditable_type, association_id, association_type
```

I have defined two polymorphic relationship in the model.

```
belongs_to :auditable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :associated, :polymorphic => true
```

When I try to access auditable and associated objects.

It works for auditable but it doen't fire query for associated.

```
Audit.last.auditable #Works
Audit.last.associated #Not working
```

Do I need to specify column names in a relationship for associated ?

Answer (score 0):

`association` conflicts with the ActiveRecord code that lets `belongs_to` and `has_many` work. If you can’t rename your columns, you’ll have to use a different name for the associated model and manually specify the foreign key and type [as documented here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to). With the example parent model name `attachment`:

```
belongs_to :attachment, :polymorphic => true, :foreign_key => :association_id, :foreign_type: :association_type
```

Comment: It returns lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x007fffdf2cfff8

Comment: haha okay. I suspect `association` is a reserved word in ActiveRecord. Can you think of another name for the related model?

Comment: I know I can fix this by changing my model name. But there is no other alternative to fix this issue instead of changing model name ?

Comment: Part of the price you pay for using an “opinionated” framework like Rails is accepting that some things are off-limits. `association` has a meaning in ActiveRecord. You’ll have to find an acceptable alternative name.

Comment: I can understand that but our code base is very old and at this stage I cannot change the column names. That's why I am looking for other alternative path.